# How to check whether folder exists on multiple servers?

Tags: c#, powershell

I have written below PowerShell script in one server to search for folder existence in other servers.

```cs
$Servers = Get-Content C:\scripts\serverlist.txt
foreach ($Server in $Servers) {
    $Test = Test-Path -Path "\\$Server\c$\Documents and Settings\"
    if ($Test -eq $true) {
        Write-Host "Path exists on $Server."
    } else {
        Write-Host "Path NOT exist on $Server."
    }
}
```

I am getting correct answer if I search for folders present in same server, but if I search for folders present in other server am getting "Path NOT exist on $Server" even though it is present.

Later I tried this one. With this also am facing the same issue

```
Get-Content c:\Users\jason\Documents\Scripts\Serverlist.txt |
    Select-Object @{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$_}},
        @{Name='FolderExist';Expression={Test-Path "\\$_\c$\program files\folder"}}
```

Also, please let me know if there is any method for this using C#.

Comment: Do you have permissions to access the folder on Remote computers. Many a times, if your `access is denied` to the folders, you might end up getting the `Path NOT exist`, even if it exists!

Comment: Apparently your account doesn't have permission to access administrative shares on other servers.

Comment: Path c:\Documents and Settings ? that's wierd one
Test-path returns $true, but this path clearly does not exist (at least on my windows 2012r2 server and my win10 laptop:)

Comment: When I try to list content of  c:\Documents and Settings   - i get Access denied. 
I can however list content of c:\documents and settings\<MyUserName> 
Maybe try a different path :)

Comment: Likely a permissions issue, but remember on modern versions of Windows `C:\Documents and Settings` is a symlink that actually points to `C:\Users` (it's only there for backwards compatibility to old apps with hardcoded paths)

Comment: Thank you all it worked fro me.....